# Select record by date using variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select records by date using variable.

```
DECLARE @estDate datetime
SET @estDate = (SELECT GETDATE())
SELECT Meta FROM T_TData WHERE  Estt_Date=@estDate
```

My table:

| Meta | Estt_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 2023-01-31 16:34:36.143 |
| 99 | 2023-01-31 16:34:36.143 |
| 45 | 2022-12-31 16:34:30.145 |
| 95 | 2023-01-25 16:34:36.143 |

My  meta column in table int and Estt_Date is datetime.

How can I select records of particular date using variable.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `Date` instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: FYI, (variable) assignments don't require a subquery. `SET @Variable = <expression>;` is valid syntax.

Comment: Actually, `Declare @estDate datetime = GETDATE()` is also valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can do this. Please find the following example
CREATE TABLE #tempData
(
  Meta INT,
  Estt_Date DATETIME
 )

 INSERT INTO #tempData(Meta,Estt_Date)
 VALUES
 (12,'2023-01-31 16:34:36.143'),
 (12,'2023-01-31 16:34:36.143'),
 (12,'2022-12-31 16:34:30.145'),
 (12,'2023-01-25 16:34:36.143')

 SELECT * FROM #tempData

 DECLARE @estDate DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
 SELECT * from #tempData WHERE  CAST(Estt_Date AS DATE)=@estDate

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempData
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ESTDATE DATE
SET @ESTDATE=GETDATE()
SELECT META FROM T_TDATA WHERE  ESTT_DATE>=@ESTDATE AND ESTT_DATE<DATEADD(DD,1,@ESTDATE)
```